# Search result leads to page not found

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, 404-page, http-request

The issue is that sometimes, searching for something leads to page not found. This seems to happen randomly with different search queries and layered filters, I haven't been able to reproduce it but I see it in the logs, once cache is cleaned it works again.

Example:

> "GET http://www.project.de/catalogsearch/result/index/?fcode=walnuss&manufacturer=Bette&q=Badewannen HTTP/1.1" 404 13720 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)" "-"

Seems most of them are from bots.

I've been looking through the code to see the cases when this could happen, but the result controller doesn't have any that I could see and the project uses solr, but I don't see any coresponding log entries with the same query so I am guessing it redirects sometime before.

The only other places that I found where it would redirect to 404 are:

- Standard router is missing, route never gets matched
- Router doesn't match the route/action
- Somewhere inside Enterprise_PageCache

I was hoping somebody would have some more information about exactly when this can happen or maybe had a similar problem.
The project runs on EE 1.14.0.1.